# Flutter - Nosuchmethoderror the getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

When you refresh the page, this error starts first, then it works.

> Error: The getter 'isNotEmpty' was called on null.
>   Receiver: null
>   Tried calling: isNotEmpty

```
class TreePage extends StatefulWidget {
  String vp;
  TreePage({this.vp});
  @override
  _TreePageState createState() => _TreePageState();
}


class _TreePageState extends State<TreePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text('Проверка штрафов',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      //new return Container(),

      body: new FutureBuilder(
        future: getPhoneFinal(widget.vp),

        //future: codePhone(widget.code),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          List data = snapshot.data;
          Map shtr = getByKeySh(); 
          Map shtrIm = getByKeyIm();
          Map violQnt;
          if(data.isNotEmpty){
            violQnt = getViolationQnt(data);
          }else{
            violQnt = null;
          }
          if(snapshot.hasError){
            print (snapshot.error);
            return Text('Не удалось получить ответ от сервера',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,
            fontSize: 22.0)
            );
          }
          else if(snapshot.hasData ){     
              return ListView.builder (
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length, //length of snapshot data
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {              
              return Container(              
                  child:Column(
                    children: <Widget>[  
                      (index == 0)?
                        new Container(
                          child:Column(
                        children: <Widget>[ 
                          new Text('Подтвержденные штрафы:  ${violQnt['approved_qnt']}'), 
                        ]
                        ),


                        )
                      : new Container(),


                       new Container(                                                
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'images/${shtrIm[data[index] ['VId']]}',
                            width: 50,
                            height: 50,
                          ),
                      ),

                      new Container(                                                
                          child: Image.asset(                            
                            'images/${(data[index] ['ProcessStatus']==1)? 'sts-ok.png': 'sts-no.png'}',
                            width: 50,
                            height: 50,
                          ),

                      ),
                       new Container(                                                
                          child: new Text(  

                            '${(data[index] ['IsPaid']==1)? 'Да': 'нет'}',

                          ),

                      ),

                      new Container(                                                
                          child: new Text(                           
                          //'Тип штрафа:  ${data[index]['VDescription']}'
                          'Тип штрафа: ${shtr[data[index] ['VId']]}'


                            ),
                      ),
                      new Container(                                                
                          child: new Text(                           
                          'Адрес:  ${data[index]['VLocation']}'                         
                            ),
                      ),
                      new Container(                                                
                          child: new Text(                           
                          'Дата:  ${data[index]['VTime']}'                         
                            ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
              );
            }
        );       
          }else if(!snapshot.hasData){
            return new Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          }
        }),
    );
  }

 // getFine(String vp) {}


}



Future<Map> getPhone(String phone,String code) async{
  String url = 'xxx/xxx/$phone/$code';
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  //var sts = response.statusCode;
  //log( response.statusCode);
  //  var ar = {
  //    'sts': response.statusCode,
     //'data': json.decode(response.body)
   //};
  return json.decode(response.body);
}

Future<List> getPhoneFinal(String numbCar) async{
  String url = 'xxx/xxx/$numbCar';
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  return json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
}



Map<String, String> getByKeySh() {
  return {
            '1625': 'Проезд на красный сигнал светофора',
            '1302': 'Проезд на красный сигнал светофора',
            '1230': 'Пересечение сплошной линии',
            '1301': 'Движение по встречной полосе',
            //1301 => 'Выезд на полосу встречного движения',
            '1345': 'Выезд за стоп-линию'
  };
}
  Map<String, String> getByKeyIm() {
  return {
            '1625': '1625.png',
            '1302': '1302.png',
            '1230': '1230.png',
            '1301': '1301.png',
            //1301 => '',
            '1345': '1345.png'
  };


}

Map<String, int> getViolationQnt(List data ) {
        var total_qnt = 0;
        var approved_qnt = 0;
        var paid_qnt = 0;
        var process_qnt = 0;

 // if(data.isNotEmpty){

    for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
      total_qnt++;
      if(data[i]['IsPaid'] == 1){
        paid_qnt++;
      }
      if(data[i]['IsPaid'] == 0 && data[i]['ProcessStatus'] == 1){
        approved_qnt++;
      }
      if(data[i]['IsPaid'] == 0 && data[i]['ProcessStatus'] != 1){
        process_qnt++;
      }
    }
 // }
  return {
            'total_qnt': total_qnt,
            'approved_qnt': approved_qnt,
            'paid_qnt': paid_qnt,
            'process_qnt': process_qnt,
  };


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `data.length > 0` instead of data.isNotEmpty() also can check with `snapshot.hasData`

Comment: Nice suggestion but this is not an answer. You might want to post this (and such) as a comment to the original question.

Comment: That helped! Thanks)

Comment: how to put so that after 10 elements the "More" button appears? It turns out through each element the button "More" appears. Advise something, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When your `FutureBuilder` calls it's builder method the first time you don't have data. So you should check it first.

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: getPhoneFinal(widget.vp),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            List data = snapshot.data;
            ...
          }else{
            return Container(); //or show a loading spinner
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when I used FutureBuilder. I had some delay before retrieving my result. In your case, the List data was null because the response is not received yet which justifies your error, and when data is received, it works. You might want to add a loader that waits for the response to come before going further